# How to use DateRangePicker in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I want to use DateRangePicker in Angular 2 where a user can select the date range and on submit button it should be saved in any variable.

I am using DateTimePickerDirective but unable to get selected date range.

Please help me with HTML and .ts code

Comment: Maybe adding some of your code to let others understand your problem clearer? :)

Comment: My code is not working, need some example

Comment: Take a look at: https://github.com/valor-software/angular2-quickstart. I think it's good for you.